# Collisions aren't being detected in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know why but collisions aren't being detected in my game. Its an asteroids style game and I want the bullets to destroy the asteroids, and the game to end when the ship gets hit by one, but they're passing through each other without doing any of that.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from math import sin, cos, pi

from random import randint

scr_width = 800
scr_height = 600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width, scr_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Asteroids")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
space_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/space.jpg")
red = (255, 0, 0)

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.vel_max = 12
        self.angle = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 10, 10)
        self.ship_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/ship_off.png")
        self.ship_img_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(self.ship_img, self.angle)

    def draw(self):
        self.ship_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/ship_off.png")
        self.ship_img_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(self.ship_img, self.angle)

        window.blit(self.ship_img_copy,
                    (self.x - (self.ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.y - (self.ship_img_copy.get_height()) / 2))

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.ship_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/ship_on.png")
            self.ship_img_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(self.ship_img, self.angle)
            window.blit(self.ship_img_copy,
                        (self.x - (self.ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.y - (self.ship_img_copy.get_height()) / 2))
# collision stuff
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img_copy)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x - (self.ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2,
                                self.y - (self.ship_img_copy.get_height()) / 2,
                                self.ship_img_copy.get_width(), self.ship_img_copy.get_height())

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # todo acceleration and thrust mechanics
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.vel = min(self.vel + 1, self.vel_max)
        elif self.vel > 0:
            self.vel = self.vel - 0.4
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle += 7

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle -= 7

        self.x += self.vel * cos(self.angle * (pi / 180) + (90 * pi / 180))
        self.y -= self.vel * sin(self.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
        # So that if it leaves one side it comes from the other
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = (self.y - self.vel) % 600

        elif self.y > 600:
            self.y = (self.y + self.vel) % 600

        elif self.x < 0:
            self.x = (self.x - self.vel) % 800

        elif self.x > 800:
            self.x = (self.x + self.vel) % 800


class Asteroid:

    def __init__(self):

        self.ang_change = randint(1, 5)
        self.ang = randint(0, 90) * (pi / 180)
        y_values = [1, 599]
        self.sx = randint(0, 800)
        self.sy = y_values[randint(0, 1)]
        # If object spawns from the top, it moves down instead of moving up and de-spawning immediately
        if self.sy == y_values[0]:
            self.neg = -1
        else:
            self.neg = 1
        self.speed = randint(5, 10)
        self.ang += self.ang_change
        self.asteroid_angle = randint(0, 80)
        self.asteroid_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/asteroid.png")
        self.asteroid_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asteroid_img, self.ang)

    def generate(self):
        self.ang += self.ang_change
        self.asteroid_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/asteroid.png")
        self.asteroid_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asteroid_img, self.ang)

        window.blit(self.asteroid_copy,
                    (self.sx - (self.asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.sy - (self.asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2))
# collision stuff
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.asteroid_copy)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.sx - (self.asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2,
                                self.sy - (self.asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2,
                                self.asteroid_copy.get_width(), self.asteroid_copy.get_height())


class Projectiles:

    def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.angle = angle
        self.vel = 20
        self.bullet_body = pygame.image.load("sprites/bullet.png")

    def draw(self):
        self.bullet_body = pygame.image.load("sprites/bullet.png")
# collision stuff
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x - (self.bullet_body.get_width()) / 2,
                                self.y - (self.bullet_body.get_height()) / 2, 5, 5)
        window.blit(self.bullet_body, (self.x - 2, self.y))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.bullet_body)


def redraw():
    window.blit(space_img, (0, 0))
    ship.draw()
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.generate()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw()

    pygame.display.update()

# collision stuff
def collisions():
    asteroids = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ship, asteroids, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask):
        print("hit")
        pygame.quit()
    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(asteroids, bullets, True, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)


# main loop
run = True
ship = Ship(400, 300)
next_fire = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 400
bullets = []
asteroids = []

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pygame.time.delay(35)
# collision stuff
    collisions()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 11 and pygame.time.get_ticks() >= next_fire:
            bullets.append(
                Projectiles(round(ship.x + ship.width - 6.5 // 2), round(ship.y + ship.width - 6.5 // 2), ship.angle))
            next_fire = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 400

    for bullet in bullets:
        if 800 > bullet.x > 0 and 600 > bullet.y > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel * cos(bullet.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
            bullet.y -= bullet.vel * sin(bullet.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    # To limit the number of asteroids on screen
    if len(asteroids) < 5:
        asteroids.append(Asteroid())

    for asteroid in asteroids:
        if 805 > asteroid.sx > 0 and 605 > asteroid.sy > 0:
            asteroid.sx += asteroid.speed * cos(asteroid.asteroid_angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
            asteroid.sy -= asteroid.speed * sin(asteroid.asteroid_angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180)) * asteroid.neg
            if asteroid.sx < 0:
                asteroid.sx = (asteroid.sx - asteroid.speed) % 805

            elif asteroid.sx > 805:
                asteroid.sx = (asteroid.sx + asteroid.speed) % 805

        else:
            asteroids.pop(asteroids.index(asteroid))

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ship.move()
    redraw()

pygame.quit()
```

Is it that I can't make a seperate function for collisions, or have I missed something else?

Comment: why don't you use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size instead of using `self.x` and `self.ship_img_copy.get_width()` - `self.rect = self.ship_img_cop.get_rect()`  and then you can use `self.rect.centerx` instead of `(self.x - (self.ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2`

Comment: Not sure, but in the `collisions()` function you are createing sprite groups, like `asteroids` and `bullets`, but you never assign any sprites to those groups. You'd need to do something like `asteroids.add(asteroid)` every time you instanciate a new asteroid, and not create a new sprite group every time you call `collisions()`

Comment: all collide functions use `self.rect` to check collision but you don't use it but you keep position in `self.x`, `self.y`. Really you should use `self.rect` to keep position and size - it can be used also to `blit(..., self.rect)` so you don't have to make so big calculations.

Comment: you waste time to load the same image in `draw()`. You should load it in `__init__` and keep it - ie `self.image` - and in `draw()` use it `blit(self.image, self.rect)`. If you have to rotate it then keep it as `self.image_original` and later do `self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image_original,...)` . And it is good to use the same names `self.image` in all classes - instead of `self. img_ship`, `self.img_player`, etc. becuase PyGame group can run `draw()` and then it use `self.image` and `self.rect` in all objects to draw them.

Comment: BTW: there is no need to use prefix `.asteroid_` in class `Asteroid` - i.e. `.asteroid_angle` you don;t use `.asteroid_x` and `.asteroid_y`. The same with prefix `bullet_` in `Projectiles` - you don't use `bullet_x` and `bullet_y`. It is easier when all classes has the same names for variables and methods because then you can keep different oblect in the same list or `Group()` and use `for`-loop to run the same function for all object.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test code but usually problem is that collision's function use values from `self.rect` but you don't use them but `self.x` and `self.y` to keep position.

You should do in `__init__`

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

self.rect.center = (x, y)
```

and later you can add to `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` and it will automatically calculate position for

```
blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

and for collision with other object

```
self.rect.colliderect(other.rect)
```

or with mouse in `event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

```
self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
```

to test if object was clicked (ie. button).

---

If you want to use pygame `Group`

```
asteroids = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

then you shouldn't create them inside `collisions()` but at start instead of lists

```
asteroids = []
bullets = []
```

and you should add objects to groups instead of appending to lists.

```
asteroids.add(Asteroid())
```

and you can even run function for all objects without using `for`-loop

```
asteroids.draw()
```

Comment: How do I delete objects that have left the screen?

Comment: if you use `Rect` , `Sprite` and `Group` then you could use [Rect.contains()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) or `Rect.colliderect` and [Sprite.kill()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill). In `move()` you can do `if not window.get_rect().contains(self.rect): self.kill()` or `if not self.rect.colliderect(window.get_rect()): self.kill()` and it should remove this object from `Group` and then group will not draw it.